# Запись атрибута value со значением, в тег input

Tags: javascript, dom

Почему не устанавливается атрибут value со значением Да/Нет ?

```js
var checkFamily = document.getElementById('checkFamily');
checkFamily.onclick = function () {
if(this.checked) {
 checkFamily.setAttribute('value', 'Да');
}
else {
    checkFamily.setAttribute('value', 'Нет');
}
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="form_field_checkbox" id="checkFamily" class="checkFamily"><span>ранее менялась</span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Меняется значение.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var checkFamily = document.getElementById('checkFamily');
checkFamily.onclick = function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    checkFamily.setAttribute('value', 'Да');
    document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = this.value || 'ранее менялась';
  } else {
    checkFamily.setAttribute('value', 'Нет');
    document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = this.value || 'ранее менялась';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="form_field_checkbox" id="checkFamily" class="checkFamily"><span>ранее менялась</span></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно менять текст то вот так:

*Обратите внимание в коде атрибут `value` при клике значение меняется!*

```js
var checkFamily = document.getElementById('checkFamily');
var span = document.getElementById('span');

checkFamily.onclick = function () {
if(this.checked) {
  checkFamily.setAttribute('value', 'Да');
  span.innerHTML =  'Да'; 
}
else {
    checkFamily.setAttribute('value', 'Нет');
    span.innerHTML =  'Нет'; 
}
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="form_field_checkbox" id="checkFamily" class="checkFamily"><span id="span">ранее менялась</span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Я прописал в input, value="Нет", но если человек не трогал галочку вообще, а другие поля заполнил и потом отправил форму, то получаю по данному checkbox,  -  undefined

Comment: Правильно указано.

Comment: данные отправляются в Google Sheets.

Comment: покажите весь код

Comment: Нет возможности написать в личку. Только если сообщите как вам показать по другому.

Comment: https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-submit-an-html-form-to-google-sheets-without-google-forms-b833952cc175

Comment: они в json: $('#submit-form').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $form.serializeObject()
  }).success(
    // do something
  );
})

Comment: Ответ должен быть типа такого: {text-field: "", checkbox-1: "on", checkbox-2: "on", dropdown: ""}  Выведите переменную  
  var result =  $form.serializeObject(); в консоль, какой будет ваш результат

Comment: Не понятно как это сделать. Я не настолько знаю всё хорошо.

Comment: там где  // do something - вставьте код var result = $form.serializeObject() console.log(result); и сделайте скрин

Answer (score 1):

Если желаете изменить текст:

```js
checkFamily.onclick = function () {
  if(this.checked) {
    text.innerText = 'Да';
  }
  else {
    text.innerText = 'Нет';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="form_field_checkbox" id="checkFamily" class="checkFamily">
    <span id="text">ранее менялась</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Код работает! Попробуйте прописать дефолтное значение value для input

```
var checkFamily = document.getElementById('checkFamily');

checkFamily.onclick = function () {
if(this.checked) {
    checkFamily.setAttribute('value', 'Да');
}
else {
    checkFamily.setAttribute('value', 'Нет');
}
}
```

Comment: Работает, но не корректно. Поставил value="Нет", если галочка не поставлена, то приходит на сервер undefined (а нужно - "Нет"), если поставлена галочка, то приходит "Да" - это как и предполагалось.